# Vue Router or Axios interferes with JWT auth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, axios, jwt

So i have a JWT based authorization and a Vue router. I have a path there:

```
  {
      path: '/admindashboard',
      component: AdminDashboard
    },
```

and a router beforeEach function

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // If the route doesnt require authentication
  if (!to.meta.requiresAuth) next()
  // If the route requires authentication
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

    if (!token) next('/login')
    const response = axios.post('/verifyToken')
    const status = response.status
    next()
    if (!status === 200) return '/login'
  }
})
```

and i have also a backend API endpoint to get all the names of collection:

```
exports.getDBList = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { db } = mongoose.connection;
  const collections = await db.listCollections().toArray();
  const collectionNames = collections.map(collection => collection.name);
  const collectionNamesForQuiz = collectionNames.filter(
    item => item !== 'users'
  );
  try {
    res.status(200).json({ data: collectionNamesForQuiz });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error });
  }
};
```

and when i call it with router (from the pinia store), it doesnt work. And when i call it with router commented, it works!
Like how? There are two independent pieces of code!

```
exports.verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', '');
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'No auth' });
  }
  try {
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    return res.status(200).json(decodedToken);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Incorrect token' });
  }
};
```

And axios:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
```

I didnt specify any form of auth for this request, and yet the router is messing thins up. Like how they are connected? I know that axios sets a header with token, but on any level it is required...

Comment: first issue ... `axios.post` returns a `Promise` so `response.status` will always be `undefined` ... you'd need `const response = await axios.post('/verifyToken')` (after making the enclosing function `async` of course)

Comment: second thing that looks odd `!status === 200` ... since `!status` will always be `true` or `false` it can never `=== 200` ... did you mean `status !== 200` or `!(status === 200)`?

Comment: are you related to user "Connor Nusser"

Comment: thanks sir for your answer. that`s right, couple of stupid bugs. Thanks for the the time, i will fix that. Can I use if( !response.ok)? who is Connor Nusser?

Comment: he used exactly the phrase `I didnt specify any form of auth for this request, and yet the router is messing thins up. Like how they are connected? I know that axios sets a header with token, but on any level it is required...` in his question ... like ... exactly!!!